# Visual studio 17 debug properties not exporting to template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm using an external library in a C++ project which needs to have some additional library directories etc. added on the project properties to enable proper build/debugging. As I am going to be using this setup a lot I have tried to make a project template via Project -> Export template and then followed the usual steps.

I then made a new project from this template, and it built correctly; however two properties from the debugging section don't seem to have copied over successfully, and as such it doesn't run correctly:

Debug - Command
Debug - Command arguments.

Is this an error or do debug properties not get saved in a project template. Is there any way to save them, so I don't have to keep typing them when I create new projects?

Comment: The last sentence is correct, debug settings are considered user-specific and are therefore saved in a projectname.vcxproj.user file.  You could try adding it to the .zip archive yourself, perhaps.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense, many thanks.